# Enabling onboard WiFi during USB install

Tags: wireless, live-usb

How do you enable an onboard WiFi adapter that's not detected by the live USB installer?  (I'm starting from Windows 10 and creating a USB boot device with Universal USB Installer.)  My motherboard is an [Asus Z97 Deluxe/USB 3.1](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z97DELUXEUSB_31/HelpDesk/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's not detected automatically, it may use a proprietary driver and you'd have to install it over ethernet first and then enable the driver.

Comment: So how do I add it over ethernet?  All I have is a WiFi connection.  (Unfortunately, I live in a house that doesn't offer a wired connection.)  In Windows 10, it's listed as a "Broadcom 801.11ac Network Adapter".  Asus doesn't offer any Linux drivers for it.  Suggestions?

Comment: Well, your option is download the driver to a USB memory from windows 10 and then install the driver in Ubuntu. An alternative to ethernet connection could be USB tethering using a smartphone (I'm not sure if it works).